# работа с ftp android

Tags: android, android-sdk, ftp

Допустим есть некоторый ftp сервер, в настройках своего приложения я имею : адрес, логин и пароль. Необходимо найти метод отправки списка файлов на ftp сервер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя [Apache Commons libraries](https://commons.apache.org/) требуемое можно осуществить [следующим](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601030) образом:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = null;

try {
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect("hostname");

    if (ftpClient.login("login", "password")) {
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        String data = "/sdcard/filename.m4a";

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
        boolean result = con.storeFile("/filename.m4a", in);
        in.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Обработка ошибок
}
```